# How to show custom message when click on CheckIn button VS 2013 Pending Changes tab

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I want to show message box with some information (like Please check in same code to another TFS branch or etc..) to user when they click on CheckIn button in pending changes tab in VS 2013.
Is there any way to show message before check in the changes.

Regards,
Rajendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can custom check-in policies and call message box to show information in Evaluate() method.

```
public override PolicyFailure[] Evaluate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check in same code to another TFS branch");
            string s = PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChanges.First().ServerItem;
            string proposedComment = PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.Comment;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(proposedComment))
            {
                return new PolicyFailure[] {
                new PolicyFailure("Please provide some comments about your check-in", this) };
            }
            else
            {
                return new PolicyFailure[0];
            }
        }
```

About how to custom check-in policies, you can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) article. (apply to VS 2015, the windows registry entry path is different, for VS 2015, replace 8.0 to 14.0. For 64 bit OS: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies)

Comment: Hi starain, Thank you for solution, but I am not seeing TeamFoundation register key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\    I am using VS 2013 premium. Do i need to install any other tools

Comment: @user1915370 Yes, for VS 2013, the register key path is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0.... (64 bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\....

Comment: Yes, Under 12.0 regkey I am not seeing **TeamFoundation** regkey.

Comment: @user1915370 Is it 32 bit OS? Check it HKEY_CURRENT_USER.